# Making a function that displays an error message in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, function

I want to be able to create a function that totals up work hours, but displays an error message once the the employee has reached a certain amount of hours that week (i.e. "This employee cannot enter overtime").

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE FUNCTION sumHours(id INT)
RETURNS INT
BEGIN
    RETURN (SELECT sum(hours_worked) FROM shifts WHERE employee_id = id);
END;// 
DELIMITER ;
```

I was able to make the function to total the number of hours, but I'm not sure how to add an error message to the above function.

Comment: this is much better to do in your client